# File not found error with FMOD FMOD_OUTPUTTYPE_WAVWRITER_NRT

Tags: android, fmod

i'm trying to run FMOD in WAVWRITER_NRT mode. I was modifying the example bundled with FMOD, but I always get an error on FMOD_System_Init. It says that the file cannot be found.

I thought it would create a file to write output to. I have also tried placing a wav file with that name into that location. Still, I always have this error.

Here is the code:

```
result = FMOD_System_Create(&gSystem);
CHECK_RESULT(result);

result = FMOD_System_SetOutput(gSystem, FMOD_OUTPUTTYPE_WAVWRITER_NRT);
CHECK_RESULT(result);

result = FMOD_System_Init(gSystem, 4, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, "/sdcard/fmod/out.wav");
CHECK_RESULT(result);

result = FMOD_System_CreateSound(gSystem, "/sdcard/fmod/test1.mp3", FMOD_CREATESTREAM, 0, &gSound);
CHECK_RESULT(result);
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the manifest.